# Are there examples where interpretivist findings have been confirmed by (post-)positivist methodology?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, scientific-method, social-sciences

Social sciences, especially sociology, embrace a distinction between interpretivism <sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipositivism)</sup> and (post-)positivism <sup>[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositivism)</sup>. Some social scientist embrace one method over the other and some speak in favor of both. Are there any findings discovered by interpretivist methodology which were also confirmed by (post-)positivist methodology?

Comment: See e.g. [Davies-Fitchett, Interpretivist and Positivist Insights Into Museum Consumption](https://www.acrwebsite.org/volumes/11601/volumes/e05/E-05), which finds that "*the two studies are both highly conformist to their respective paradigmatic schools, yet report common findings and use similar explanations to justify and elaborate their discussions*". However, "confirm" is not the word I would use in this context, it presupposes a shared framework of concepts and criteria that does not exist.